# Alembic --autogenerate tries to recreate every table

Tags: python, alembic

I am trying to autogenerate an alembic revision for the first time against a pre-existing database but when I run the following command

```
alembic revision --autogenerate
```

It generates a migration which attempts to create every table and index in my database. Similar to this:

```
def upgrade():
    ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.create_table('table1',
    sa.Column('id', sa.SmallInteger(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('name', sa.String(length=100), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('desc', sa.Text(), nullable=True),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id'),
    sa.UniqueConstraint('name'),
    schema='schema1'
    )
    op.create_index(op.f('ix_index1'), 'table1', ['name'], unique=False, schema='schema1')
    ... all my other tables/indexes ..


def downgrade():
    ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.drop_index(op.f('ix_index1'), table_name='table1', schema='schema1')
    op.drop_table('table1', schema='schema1')
    ... all my other tables/indexes ..
```

Then if I try and run the migration it fails because the objects already exist:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) relation "table1" already exists
```

So it looks to me like alembic thinks that my database doesn't contain any tables, but it does.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Could it be you haven't created an initial migration?
[http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/tutorial.html#running-our-first-migration](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/tutorial.html#running-our-first-migration) Judging by your question I'm assuming your database is already created. You need to tell alembic the current state of the DB so it knows what to auto generate.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26275041/alembic-sqlalchemy-does-not-detect-existing-tables. When working with the non-standard schema ('schema1' instead of 'public'), you need to configure your context accordingly ('include_schmas=True').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Configure alembic to look at your database

Have you set the target_metadata to your Base meta data?

From the [documentation](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/autogenerate.html).

> To use autogenerate, we first need to modify our env.py so that it
>   gets access to a table metadata object that contains the target.
>   Suppose our application has a declarative base in myapp.mymodel. This
>   base contains a MetaData object which contains Table objects defining
>   our database. We make sure this is loaded in env.py and then passed to
>   EnvironmentContext.configure() via the target_metadata argument. The
>   env.py sample script used in the generic template already has a
>   variable declaration near the top for our convenience, where we
>   replace None with our MetaData. Starting with:

```
# add your model's MetaData object here
# for 'autogenerate' support
# from myapp import mymodel
# target_metadata = mymodel.Base.metadata 
target_metadata = None
```

> we change to:

```
from myapp.mymodel import Base
target_metadata = Base.metadata
```

Comment: I did that but still. For example, I ran the autogeneret for a entity and it has created the table for that entity. After a while I added a new entity and run the with 'autogenerate' again. Was created a new migration file with the statements to create the new and also the existing one

Comment: @RodrigoEstevao, this answer is six years old, I haven't used alembic for years. Have you done `alembic upgrade`? Can you check your revision number?