# Alembic - sqlalchemy does not detect existing tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I've asked a question ([Alembic - sqlalchemy initial migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26251094/alembic-sqlalchemy-initial-migration)) on how to detect tables by using

```
target_metadata = Base.metadata
```

for

```
alembic revision --autogenerate -m "initial migration"
```

After I've imported my models to env.py file it seemed to work fine but it does not detect actually existing tables so it creates a migration file with all tables, for example:

```
def upgrade():
    ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.create_table('Brand',
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('name', sa.String(), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('slug', sa.String(), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('date_created', sa.DateTime(), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('date_updated', sa.DateTime(), nullable=True),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id'),
    schema='Products'
    )

def downgrade():
    ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.drop_table('ProductFile', schema='Products')
```

I've  tried:

```
alembic stamp head
```

but after running that and running autogenerate command the system generates all models once again.

```
from project.apps.users.models import *
from project.apps.orders.models import *
from project.apps.products.models import *

from project.base import Base, metadata

# this is the Alembic Config object, which provides
# access to the values within the .ini file in use.
config = context.config

# Interpret the config file for Python logging.
# This line sets up loggers basically.
fileConfig(config.config_file_name)

# add your model's MetaData object here
# for 'autogenerate' support
# from myapp import mymodel
target_metadata = Base.metadata
```

How do I avoid that problem?

Edit:

ENV.py:

```
https://gist.github.com/pypetey/bb65807ce773d8baeaf1
```

I dropped the db and ran a migration

```
(env) D:\projekty\test>alembic revision --autogenerate
INFO  [alembic.migration] Context impl MSSQLImpl.
INFO  [alembic.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table u'Users.Country'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table u'Products.Brand'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table u'Users.User'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table u'Products.Product'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table u'Products.ProductFile
'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table u'Orders.Order'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table u'Products.Category'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table u'Products.Review'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table u'Users.UserAddress'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table u'Orders.OrderItem'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table u'Orders.OrderStatus'
Generating D:\projekty\test\alembic\versions\1c6337c144a7_.py ... done

(env) D:\projekty\test>alembic upgrade head
INFO  [alembic.migration] Context impl MSSQLImpl.
INFO  [alembic.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.migration] Running upgrade None -> 1c6337c144a7, empty message

(env) D:\projekty\test>alembic revision --autogenerate
INFO  [alembic.migration] Context impl MSSQLImpl.
INFO  [alembic.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table u'Users.Country'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table u'Products.Brand'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table u'Users.User'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table u'Products.Product'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table u'Products.ProductFile
'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table u'Orders.Order'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table u'Products.Category'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table u'Products.Review'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table u'Users.UserAddress'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table u'Orders.OrderItem'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table u'Orders.OrderStatus'
Generating D:\projekty\test\alembic\versions\5abb204549f_.py ... done
```

Comment: What does `alembic current` return?

Comment: Have you tried running the migration on an empty database first? Say by running `alembic revision --autogenerate ...`, editing the migration file if necessary, running `alembic upgrade head`, and running `alembic revision --autogenerate ...` again to confirm an empty migration file is generated?

Comment: @dgilland I've crecreated the db, ran the migration and ran the autogenerate again. It did not help. Check my updated post.

Comment: After you run the `alembic upgrade head`, what does `alembic current` return? Also, after running the upgrade, can you inspect the database and confirm whether the tables were created, whether the `alembic_version` table exists, and what the contents of `alembic_version` are? From what you describe, it seems like none of the tables are being created. Do you have permission to create tables on the database?

Comment: They were created from scratch. But even after another autogenerate it did try to create them again. I do have all permissions. Alembic current returned that migration was applied (I don't have exact console logs here) and it really was but still tried to create tables again

Comment: Very strange. Can you run the migration process for a SQLite database to see how that goes?

Comment: Sure, I'll try that on monday :)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I had this exact same issue - I don't know if it still affects you. For me, the problem was caused because the schema I was using was not the default - I think the same thing is happening for you, since you're using a "Products" schema. I posted an issue at:

[https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/alembic/issue/281/autogenerate-fails-to-detect-existing](https://web.archive.org/web/20151127114350/https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/alembic/issues/281/autogenerate-fails-to-detect-existing)

And with a little bit of guidance, managed to resolve the problem by passing a parameter `include_schemas=True` to the `EnvironmentContext.configure` call in both `run_migrations_*` functions in the alembic/env.py module.

See the [docs](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/api/runtime.html?highlight=include_schemas#alembic.runtime.environment.EnvironmentContext.configure.params.include_schemas):

> If True, autogenerate will scan across all schemas located by the
> SQLAlchemy **get_schema_names()** method, and include all differences in
> tables found across all those schemas. When using this option, you may
> want to also use the **EnvironmentContext.configure.include_object**
> option to specify a callable which can filter the tables/schemas that
> get included.

Comment: This is an aside, but related: ability to control what db tables are considered "existing":  http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/api/runtime.html#alembic.runtime.environment.EnvironmentContext.configure.params.include_object  and some older discussion about this:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy-alembic/2HJ9J6PiQsk

Comment: This option does what I want for the specified schema, but it also checks for differences in all other schemas. Is there a way that I can have it be aware of the specified schema but ignore all others?

Answer (score 6):

I have an observation.
Metadata imported to the `env.py` in alembic, must have all model metadata.
So all models must be loaded before calling Base.
So,
`db_setup.py` will have,

```
...
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()
...
```

and `models.py` will have,

```
from .db_setup import Base
from sqlalchemy import Column, String
class TestModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = "test"
    field_1 = Column(String)
    ...
```

Now, in the `main.py`,

```
from flask import Flask
...
from models.setup import Base
app = Flask(__name__)
...
```

Finally, in the alembic `env.py`,

```
...
...
from main import Base # Not from db_setup!
target_metadata = Base.metadata
...
...
```

Comment: This worked for me, by far the easiest answer to implement. TLDR: Import your base.metadata from wherever your tables are initilized.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much, I've been struggling with this stuff for a while already, and this is exactly the solution I was looking for!

Answer (score -1):

In case this helps anybody else; if you are using the fastapi template, make sure the new model is added to db/base.py file.

Comment: You should specify which template because there are many FastAPI templates